# "Отдохнуть" и "вдохновение": разбор по составу

Tags: словообразование, морфемика, морфемный-разбор

На уроке с учителем поспорили, что слово "отдохнуть" не имеет приставки. В интернете везде написано, что её нет, но она говорит, что приставка там есть. После нашей дискуссии она спросила: если в этом слове нет приставки, то как насчёт "вдохновение"? Гугл пишет, что приставки там тоже нет.
Пожалуйста, объясните наиболее полно: как правильно и почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно сказать, что оба взгляда на проблему возможны.

Во-первых, заметьте, что интернет — очень опасный источник, и его использование может привести к далеко не лучшим последствиям.

Во-вторых, *отдохнуть* и *вдохновение* являются исторически однокоренными словами: у всех них можно выделить корень *дох*. (Тогда, конечно, слова будут члениться так: *от-дох-ну-ть* и *в-дох-н-ов-ени-е*.) Дело в том, что когда-то давно они были образованы от глагола *дохн**у**ть*, значащего "вздохнуть, сделать вдох или выдох" (отсюда и корень *дох*). Поэтому точка зрения учителя является верной.

Тем не менее совершенно естественно, что вам не хочется выделять приставки в этих словах: ведь ни с какими вздохами *вдохновение* и *отдохнуть* не ассоциируется! И такой подход тоже будет правильным, ведь произошла **деэтимологизация**, то есть утратилась связь со словом-прародителем. (В этом случае членение такое: *отдох-ну-ть* и *вдохнов-ени-е*.) Так, ваше представление о морфемном составе тоже верно. (Вы можете сослаться на авторитетный "Школьный словарь строения слов русского языка" З. А. Потихи (М.: Просвещение, 1987), чтобы подтвердить свою точку зрения.)

*(В ответе используются сведения из "Толкового словаря русского языка с включением сведений о происхождении слов" РАН, "Словаря морфем русского языка" А. И. Кузнецовой и Т. Ф. Ефремовой, "Школьного словаря строения слов русского языка" З. А. Потихи.)*

Answer (score 1):

Надо смотреть в словообразовательных словарях, а не просто "в интернете". Например, в словаре Тихонова читаем:

отдох-ну-ть

"Вдохновение" у Тихонова не нашел, но к слову "отдохнуть" оно не имеет отношения.
Интересно, почему ваш учитель не привел слова "вдохнуть", "вдох", "дыхание"? Они уж явно проще, чем "вдохновение"... и точно так же не имеют отношения к слову "отдохнуть".

> > Пожалуйста, объясните наиболее полно: как правильно и почему?

Ну, потому что язык непрерывно меняется - в частности, появляются новые слова, в которых могут изменяться значения старых корней и появляться новые корни. Сейчас уже никто не связывает слова "отдых", "отдохнуть" и т.п. со словом "дыхание". Появился новый корень: "отдох" ("отдых"), означающий "восстановление сил" и что-то еще в этом роде.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, в учебной грамматике существуют **два метода решения подобных задач:** в одном случае непроизводное в современном языке слово не делится на морфемы, а в другом ― выделяются приставки и суффиксы, если они, а также корень слова,  имеют понятное значение для современных носителей языка.

Вдохнуть, выдохнуть, отдохнуть, вдохновить, передохнуть и т.д. ― все эти слова имеют один и тот же корень и всем понятные по значению приставки В, ВЫ, ОТ, ПЕРЕ, и было бы разумно выделять их в слове. Но пока существуют две школы, эти споры будут продолжаться.

Итак, один из вариантов разбора: **от/дох/ну/ть, в/дох/н/овени/е,** сравнить: возник/ну/ть ― возник/н/овени/е.

**О вдохновении:** [ВДОХНОВИТЬ | etymolog.ruslang.ru](http://etymolog.ruslang.ru/vinogradov.php?id=vdochnovit)

**Вот схема образования слова**: вдохнуть ― вдохновение  ― вдохновить, то есть глагол "вдохновить" вторичен по отношению к существительному "вдохновение".

Comment: "Всем понятные по значению приставки" -- ну вообще не правда, и вопрос -- отличное тому доказательство. Во всяком случая "всем" некорректно. Все-таки переразложение -- это совершенно нормальный процесс. Вы же в "белка" не выделяете корень *бел*?..

Comment: И, честно говоря, не нравится мне соединение двух морфем в одну: ведь *в(-)дох(-)н-**ов**-и-ть* 》в(-)дох(-)н-ов-ени-е...

Comment: 1) В "белке" я и корень "бел" не выделяю (в нашей реальности белки рыжие),  здесь только этимологический корень можно выделить. 2) Формант ОВ в данном случае не является самостоятельным,  суффикс ОВЕНИ усекается до ОВ. Обычная практика при словообразовании.

Comment: 2) практика такая есть, да, но мне ближе подход, который в словаре морфем Кузнецовой используется, к примеру. 1) ну так здесь похожая ситуация.

Answer (score 0):

В этимологическом отношении "вдохновение" связано с вдохом, дыханием (new.gramota.ru)
    А слово "дыханием" связано с отдыхом. Вообще, это время для восстановления сил. Связь прослеживается: отдохнуть - ПЕРЕДОХнуть, отдышаться; прекратить какую-то работу (отдохнуть) и дать себе время, чтобы организм пришел в спокойное состояние и дыхание восстановилось. ([Этимология слова "ОТДЫХ" | Ответы Mail.Ru](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/47031307))
                    Глагол «отдыхать» за два последних века довольно сильно изменил набор своих значений Например, у него были значения «не умереть, остаться живым» и «успокоиться, убедившись в том, что опасность миновала»: Я подумал, что дедушка умер <…>, но Параша скоро воротилась и сказала, что дедушка начал было томиться, но опять отдохнул (С. Т. Аксаков. Детские годы Багрова-внука); Для шутки камешек лукнул / И так его — зашиб, что чуть он отдохнул (И. Дмитриев. Два голубя) … с одним нахалом казаком, которого за насмешки я хватил неловко по голове нагайкою <…> да, к счастию, он отдохнул (М. Н. Загоскин. Юрий Милославский, или Русские в 1612 году); — Фу, братец, как ты меня напугал, — проговорил Заруцкий, садясь на канапе, — насилу могу отдохнуть! (М. Н. Загоскин. Вечер на Хопре). 
                   Вообще раньше отдых был больше связан с дыханием (отдохнуть как отдышаться или перевести дух).
                     В XX веке значение избавления от усталости стало у слов отдыхать и отдых основным. У них также развилась идея не-работы и особым образом проводимого досуга: проводить на заслуженный отдых, т. е. на пенсию, дом отдыха, парк культуры и отдыха, зона отдыха, отдыхающие, культурно отдыхать (что бы это ни значило), Я уже отдохнул (в этом году уже съездил в отпуск) и т. д. (bookitut.ru  Russkij-so-slovarem.20.html)